# PHP array - sum values of the same key

Tags: php, arrays, count, key

I have php array...

```
Array
(    
   [pages] => Array
       (
            [/stream/apple] => 2
            [/stream/melon] => 1
            [/stream/orange] => 3
            [/stream/kiwi] => 1
       )
)
Array
(    
   [pages] => Array
       (
            [/stream/apple] => 1
       )
)
Array
(    
   [pages] => Array
       (
            [/stream/kiwi] => 1
            [/stream/melon] => 4
       )
)
...
```

...there is more Arrays

How can i return something like this...

```
/stream/apple = 3

/stream/melon = 5

/stream/orange = 3

/stream/kiwi = 2
```

I can't find any sample how to do...
Maybe someone can help me!

Comment: do you mean you have main array has three another array,, because as i see there are three array and not one array

Comment: Yes, this is just a part of whole array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not specific enough to make conclusive advice, in case you want to do it by code, and not from a SQL query, you could use a for each on the first array, and add the values from the others, here is an example.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $val){
  if (array_key_exists($key,$array2))  $array1[$key] += $array2[$key];
  if (array_key_exists($key,$array3))  $array1[$key] += $array3[$key];
}
```

The ***foreach*** loop allows you to go through an array without needing to worry about the it's lenght.

So you then use the ***$key*** to store the value of the array's key as you loop through it.

And ***$val*** to store the value of the array in that key.

You then use a very useful function called ***array_key_exists(key , array)*** to check if the key you're in exists in the other arrays, and if it does, you add up it's value to the first array.

Hope it helps!

***edit***

To loop through an infinite number of arrays, you can use the same procedure.
Here is how to do it.

```
  // You have all the arrays stored in $array_Nest
  // And you will store the totals in $array_Total

  foreach($array_Nest as $key_Nest => $val_Nest){    
    foreach ($array_Total as $key_Total => $val_Total){    
      if (array_key_exists($key_Total,$array_Nest[$key_Nest])){    
        $array_Total[$key_Total] += $array2[$key_Nest][$key_Total];    
      }    
    }
  }
```

So basically each $array_Nest[$key_Nest] is an array, from then on you only need to do the same procedure as before.

Comment: And what to do if i have more than three arrays? For example 50 !

Comment: You could put them all into 1 array and use 2 foreach, one that loops through the all the arrays, and another one for inside of each array. It's the same procedure you just need to make sure the one you're using to store the totals has all the fields the other ones could have.